# Sort array of objects by a key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I want to sort an array of objects by a key "position". In my array the objects "position" is: 0, 1 , 3, 2. I want to sort them by the "position".

```
    "images": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b04"
        },
        "position": 0,
        "name": "1540302062678adidas-fashion-feet-1225136.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b05"
        },
        "position": 1,
        "name": "1540302064570adult-agency-business-380769.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b07"
        },
        "position": 3,
        "name": "1540302067059adult-body-businessman-652347.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b06"
        },
        "position": 2,
        "name": "1540302066875adult-beard-blurred-background-936072.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:12.000Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go.

P.S: I have used lodash orderBy function.

```js
var abc =  [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b04"
        },
        "position": 0,
        "name": "1540302062678adidas-fashion-feet-1225136.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b05"
        },
        "position": 1,
        "name": "1540302064570adult-agency-business-380769.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b07"
        },
        "position": 3,
        "name": "1540302067059adult-body-businessman-652347.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:13.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bcf24f8b639a936d5471b06"
        },
        "position": 2,
        "name": "1540302066875adult-beard-blurred-background-936072.jpg",
        "created_at": {
            "$date": "2018-10-23T13:41:12.000Z"
        }
    }
]

console.log(_.orderBy(abc, ['position'], ['asc']))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! thank you, that's awsome!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!